# Sauerbraten with a 1.1 pound beef rump roast

Tags: cooking-time

The recipe I'm using says to roast a 3.5-4 pound sauerbraten roast at 325F for approximately 4 hours. I'm making the recipe quite a bit smaller with a 1.1 pound roast.

Should I change the cooking time/temperature? I'm new to roasts, so I really appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 3):

Sauerbraten is meant to be cooked low and slow (schmoren), not like an American roast which has to be removed from the oven as soon as it reaches a target internal temperature. Keep both the oven temperature and the 4 hour time, do not remove it after it reaches the target temperature.

For some background, read SAJ14SAJ's answer to [How can you tell when a roast is done?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43275). It is the section on low and slow roasting that applies to Sauerbraten.

Comment: Plenty of low and slow cooks use thermometers.  It is possible to overcook this (and any) cut.  I am not sure what is not applicable in my answer.  I did not make any reference to American roast. I did correct a typo in the temperature range that I found.

Comment: The American roast was an assumption on my side why you are suggesting the wrong method for this dish. It is made in the oven and without liquid, but nevertheless cooked like a stew, so 4 hours are normal even for smaller pieces.

Comment: I spent some time on Google comparing temperatures for sauerbraten. I then simply suggested using a thermometer to check for doneness.   With all due respect, all else is assumption on your part.

Comment: @moscafj The point here is that to the best of my knowledge, "using a thermometer to check for doneness" is wrong in the case of a Sauerbraten. So I think that any assumptions here are not really important - you and I simply have a different opinion on which method is appropriate for it. I can still remove the comparison to the roast, if you wish, or also the reference to your answer. I will still insist that it shouldn't be removed when the target temperature is reached, but kept for the full 4 hours.

Comment: how about removing reference to me from your answer?  That way the community can just value the responses as they see fit.

Comment: @moscafj done. Sorry about the whole issue, sometimes I can have amazing blind spots as to how my formulations come across. I hope I plan to learn from it this time and not repeat the same mistake, but if I make another one with similar consequences, don't hesitate to point it out in a very direct way and also suggest a correcting action outright.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the original oven temperature.  Use a thermometer.  A quick Google of recipes indicates a target temperature of 145 - 185F...  165F seems common.  Figure it will take a less time then the recipe you are following.